# How to give user the choice to reenter a loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

Everyone

I have some code and i'm unsure how to get the loop to stop based on the user's answer. If the request is yes then continue the loop, but print the final statement if answered no. Thank you to all who help with this task.

```
    import random

char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!#$%&*/\(')"

while 1:
    password_len = int(input("How many characters do you want your password? "))
    password_count = int(input("How many passwords do you want? "))

    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password = ""

        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(char)
            password = password + password_char

        print("Here is your password:", password)

        ans = input("Do you need more passwords? ").lower()

        if ans == "yes":
            
            
        else:
            print("Thank you for your service, goodbye.")
```

Comment: add a `break` statement after the `print('Thank you')`

Comment: `password = ''.join(random.choice(char) for _ in range(password_len))`

Comment: `if ans != "yes":` or you need to add a `pass`

Answer (score 0):

```py
    import random

char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!#$%&*/\(')"
flag = True

while flag :
    password_len = int(input("How many characters do you want your password? "))
    password_count = int(input("How many passwords do you want? "))

    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password = ""

        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(char)
            password = password + password_char

        print("Here is your password:", password)

        ans = input("Do you need more passwords? ").lower()

        if ans == "yes":
            continue
            
        else:
            flag = False
            print("Thank you for your service, goodbye.")
            break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).